# how to understand scala placeholder

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala, I don't understand this code below.

- for //1, what is the =>Boolean ? the "matcher" is same as the one 
  in //2 ?
- in //3, why there are two place holder _ ?

Code:

```
def filesMatching(query: String, matcher: (String, String) => Boolean //1 ) = {
  for (
    file <- filesHere;  // filesHere is a function that returns an Array of files
    if matcher(file.getName, query) //2
  ) yield file
}
def filesEnding(query: String) =
  filesMatching(query, (fileName: String, query: String) => fileName.endsWith(query))

def filesRegex(query: String) =
  filesMatching(query, _.matches(_) //3)
```

code is from here : https://mbonaci.github.io/scala/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1), `filesMatching` is a function that takes two arguments, one a `String` called `query` and the other a function `(String, String) => Boolean`, i.e. a function taking a pair of strings and returning a boolean, called `matcher`.

In (2), this function is being called with the strings `file.getName` and `query` as arguments, returning the `Boolean` used by the `if`.

That leaves us the two underscores in (3). There are a couple of ways underscores get used in Scala, all of which basically amount to "I don't need a name for this thing". Here it's a shortening of the anonymous function syntax. Remember that `filesMatching`'s second argument is a function that takes two `String`s. We could rewrite it as

```
def filesRegex(query: String) = filesMatching(query, (a, b) => a.matches(b))
```

In other words, the first `_` is a placeholder for the first argument and the second `_` is a placeholder for the second argument.

Comment: then filesEnding can be rewrited to this ? def filesEnding(query: String) =  filesMatching(query, _.endsWith(_))

Answer (score 0):

This represents a function that takes 2 parameters of type String and returns a Boolean:

```
(String, String) => Boolean
```

For example, here we are invoking `filesMatching` with a function that checks if the first string ends with the second string:

```
filesMatching(query, (fileName: String, query: String) => fileName.endsWith(query))
```

This argument named `matcher` is then used in the body of `filesMatching`. As you can see, it receives 2 Strings and returns a Boolean:

```
if matcher(file.getName, query)
```

Finally, the `_` are simply a short notation for this function, each `_` corresponds to a function parameter. The last line is equivalent to:

```
filesMatching(query, (fileName: String, query: String) => fileName.matches(query))
```